# when i add bootstrap stylesheet my top left png turns invisible

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My image (.png) formatting works fine, but once I add bootstrap library to the html, the image turns invisible but the link still works.

CSS:

```
.menu-icon img {
      width: 14vw;
      height: 5vh;
      padding-bottom: 20%;
      padding-top: 10%;
      padding-left: 4%;
      position: block;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<a href="index.html" class="menu-icon">
<img src="img/image.png">
</a>
```

**Note: Other image .png still works, while it is smaller and at the bottom of the menu**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap CSS is overwriting your CSS code.

You should force html to work with your CSS using [!important](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) you can either proceed like this:

```
<a href="index.html" class="menu-icon">
<img src="img/image.png" style="width: 14vw !important;"> <!-- do the rest of styling yourself while adding !important
</a>
```

Or do it in CSS like @kblau suggested:

```
.menu-icon img {
       width: 14vw;
       height: 55px;
       padding-bottom: 20%;
       padding-top: 10%;
       padding-left: 4%;
       position: block;
       box-sizing: content-box !important;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change height to pixels and modify box sizing, it will will work even with bootstrap:

```
<style type="text/css">
       .menu-icon img {
           width: 14vw;
           height: 55px;
           padding-bottom: 20%;
           padding-top: 10%;
           padding-left: 4%;
           position: block;
           box-sizing: content-box !important;
       }
</style>
```